# .Net 4.5, how to change zone security settings via .NET Framework configuration

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

In .net 1.1 we could do something like:

- Go to “Control panel” in the Windows Start menu.
- Select “Administrative Tools” (double click)
- Select “Microsoft .NET Framework Configuration”
- Click “Configure Code Access Security Policy”
- Click “Adjust Zone Security”
- Check “Make changes to this computer” and click next.
- Select “Local Intranet”, move settings to “Full trust” and click next.
- Click “Finish” and close the window with “Microsoft .NET Framework Configuration”

How do we achieve this on a machine with 4.5?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713717.aspx):
On 32-bit computers, create a subkey under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework key in the system registry. Use the key name LegacyMyComputerZone with a DWORD value of 1.

On 64-bit computers, create a subkey under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework key in the system registry. Use the key name LegacyMyComputerZone with a DWORD value of 1. Create the same subkey under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework key.

Answer (score 0):

That tool is gone, along with CAS getting deprecated in .NET 4.0.  You'll have to run Caspol.exe from the command line.  The voodoo is shown in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx).  Summarizing from that post:

```
  caspol.exe -m -ag 1.2 -hash SHA1 -file \\share\foo\bar.dll  FullTrust
```

Where `-m` selects "make changes to this computer", `-ag 1.2` selects the local intranet zone and `-url` selects the filename on the share.  You can tell why CAS got deprecated :)

Do check if you actually need it, files stored in the local intranet zone got full trust by default already in .NET 3.5 SP1.